Failed to resolve import "react-awesome-loaders" from "src/App.jsx". Does the file exist?

I am getting the following error:  Failed to resolve import "react-awesome-loaders" from "src/App.jsx". Does the file exist?
I have tried deleting node modules and npm i again as well as npm i react-awesome-loaders
Here is my vite-config.js file:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "path";

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: resolve(__dirname, "./src") }],
  },
  server: {
    fs: {
      cachedChecks: false,
    },
  },
});

The error randomly popped up. It was working yesterday
This is the app.jsx:
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BackgroundBeams } from "./components/ui/background-beams";
import { FlipWords } from "./components/ui/flip-words";
import { BoltLoader } from "react-awesome-loaders";
import {} from "react-awesome-loaders";
import Avatars from "./components/Avatars";
import { Compare } from "./components/ui/compare";

this is my package.json:
{
  "name": "dreambooth",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tabler/icons-react": "^3.24.0",
    "@tsparticles/engine": "^3.7.1",
    "@tsparticles/react": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsparticles/slim": "^3.7.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "framer-motion": "^11.13.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "eslint": "^9.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.12.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.49",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.16",
    "vite": "^6.0.1"
  }
}

